# SOAP Call from Mobilefirst Adapter

Tags: soap, wsdl, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I created Java files from SOAP WSDL and called the operation of WSDL from Adapter JS file. On returning the string I am getting below error.

```
"isSuccessful": false,
    "warnings": [],
    "errors": [
        "Runtime: Procedure return value must be a Javascript Object, it is currently a String."
    ],
    "info": []
```

This is my procedure:

```
function callSoap(CustId){
    var callMethod = new com.idea.actions.SoapCallUtil();
    var custBalance= callMethod.getBalance(CustId);
    return custBalance;
}
```

How to convert this "custBalance" String in Javascript Object.Someone please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Does this work? 
return { myResponse : custBalance}; or 
var resp = JSON.stringify(custBalance);
return {myResponse: resp};

Comment: Thanks Vivin. return {myResponse:custBalance} worked.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from an HTTP adapter should be a proper JSON.

Modify your current code from :

```
return custBalance;
```

to

```
return { myResponse : custBalance};
```

or

```
var resp = JSON.stringify(custBalance); 
return {myResponse: resp};
```